# Sequences in Music

Tags: theory, counterpoint, species-counterpoint

[image]I am doing second species counterpoint and this exercise gives me all the bottom notes and only the first 4 eighth notes. The exercise says:

*Where a sequence occurs in the given voice, use one in the added voice as well*

I believe I followed the sequence for the rest of measure 1. But how would I continue it for the second measure? I know I could just transpose measure one in the melody.

Thanks!

https://ibb.co/N2kL5bX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in the solution presented is that the C.F. sequence breaks off in beat 3, but the solution continues it into beat 4, leaving that voice unprepared for a new sequence in the second measure. (Also note that beat 4 has `F` in the counterpoint against `Eb` in the C.F., a no-no.)

In the counterpoint, on beat 3, rather than move from `Eb` to `G`, break the sequence and move from `Eb` downward. That will prepare the counterpoint for the measure 2 sequence.

Here is one simple solution:

```
X: 1
T: Counterpoint 2/8
T: proposed solution to m. 1
K: Ab major
M: 4/4
%%score V1 | V2
[V:V1] cedf edcB | A
[V:V2 clef=bass] A,2B,2C2E,2 | F,2
```

---

**Note:** The proposed solution is a transposition of a sequence appearing in Bach's Invention in C major (BWV 772).

**Mm. 3-4**
[image: Bach Invention in C Major, mm. 3-4]
([IMAGE SOURCE](https://imslp.simssa.ca/files/imglnks/usimg/5/53/IMSLP128949-WIMA.b5e1-Bach_Invention_01.pdf))

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to answer my question! :D

Comment: @DylanCataldo I'm glad it helped. The best way to say "thanks" is to upvote the answer. That would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Transposing the melody seems OK, however, there are two ways to do this. One may transpose exactly which runs the risk of leaving the key or just transpose diatonically where maybe major and minor intervals may be changed. I think the latter would work better in this type of counterpoint; the exercises seem too short to be worth changing key. A few modifications may still be needed to avoid parallel fifths and octaves, etc.